# Does Jquery 'On' work on elements copied in with element.innerHtml?

Tags: jquery

in our website we have one 'content' div in which the html is pasted in.

So for instance: `content.innerHtml = 'huge pile of html with divs and tables'`

now I want to attach an jquery event handler on one of the elements pasted in, so I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    alert('111');
    $("#PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels input").on("click", function (event) {
        alert($(this).text());
    });

});
```

I get the alert, so that code is called.
The input element is 5 levels deep under/within an element with the id 'PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels'

But, no `alert($(this).text());` is called.

Should this work, or is the way the html is entered to the dom preventing this to work?

Comment: That's the longest ID I've ever seen. A tip of the hat to you, sir.

Comment: I'm surprised at how often these questions come up about `.on` delegation with jQuery.  Makes me think they should rename the function, or maybe offer an alias in the API so it's a little better publicized.

Comment: I was redirected from the `live` help page to the `on` help page. The `live` page mentioned 'on all future created items' so i thought that would also work on `on`, but with `on` the originating element must be present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate the event to element with id `PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels` and use tag selector for its descendants of type input using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("#PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels").on("click", "input", function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

If the element (parent) to which you want to delegate the event is unknown or does not exists then you can use document instead.

```
$(docuement).on("click", "#PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels input", function (event)    {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I was redirected to the `on` method from the `live` method because the `live` method is removed in 1.9.x. Should the PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels element exist when running this code and the input can be added later, or can the PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels element also be added later (like AFTER running your proposed code)

Comment: The node should exist when this code is called. However, you can also delegate to another node further up the ladder - `content` if that's the only node you have on your page.

Comment: oh, i now read this: *Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()* I thought the `live` command could also work on elements that were created 'in the future'

Comment: Excellent!  used the `content` div to set the `on` on, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try this i have the same issue but this code solved me.

```
$(document).on("click","#PersonalMessageTemplateDropDownModels input", function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```